# iOS 6 GKChallenge generating a unique identifier?

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm currently writing a game which is heavily based on game center engagement. I want to implement in-game challenges, but the problem is I need some kind of unique identifier for each issued challenge, so that I can track challenges on my server.

I've tried to implement this via [GKChallenge](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKChallenge_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/GKChallenge) objects, which has fields:

- issueDate
- issuingPlayerID
- receivingPlayerID
- message
- state
- completionDate

The problem is that the only usable (for my case) unique field here is issueDate, but there's no way I can retrieve issueDate in issueChallenge methods.

So the question: **is it possible to generate any sort of unique ID for game center challenges? If not, is there any other workaround for challenges?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only issue GKScoreChallenges and GKAchievementChallenges through game center. And I don't see why you want to track them on your server. Game center handles the challenges and you can get the list of challenges for the local player using `loadReceivedChallengesWithCompletionHandler`.

The `GKScoreChallenge` has a `GKScore` which has a unique field (uint64_t context) that allows a game to store and retrieve additional data associated with the score.

If you don't want to use these game center features and handle the challenges through your own server you could create a GKChallenge subclass and implement your own challenge logic.